# GNOME 3 16.04 LTS front end crash during logout

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gnome

I installed GNOME as my flavor of UBUNTU 16.04 LTS on a new Dell XPS 15". So far things are going about as good as one would expect for installing UBUNTU on a laptop (lots of drivers and customization to hunt down / tweak to get acceptable performance).

One thing I noticed is that sometimes when I log out the front end crashes and I end up with a terminal shell to log in to my computer.

Is there a way to relaunch the front end from here without having to restart my computer.

I tend to do this if I am switching between the onboard Intel GPU and the NVIDIA 1050.

Crash log:

```
total 29996
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Jul 17 09:24 .
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 17 09:24 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r--  1 sumner   whoopsie        0 Jul 17 09:22 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 sumner   whoopsie 18363797 Jul 17 09:21 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 sumner   whoopsie  1569658 Jul 17 08:35 _usr_share_skypeforlinux_skypeforlinux.1000.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 17 08:26 _usr_lib_dleyna-server_dleyna-server-service.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r--  1 sumner   whoopsie        0 Jul 17 08:26 _usr_lib_dleyna-server_dleyna-server-service.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 sumner   whoopsie  2648233 Jul 17 08:26 _usr_lib_dleyna-server_dleyna-server-service.1000.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 17 08:22 _sbin_plymouthd.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Jul 17 08:22 _sbin_plymouthd.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie  2010646 Jul 17 08:22 _sbin_plymouthd.0.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 17 04:50 _usr_bin_gnome-keyring-daemon.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Jul 17 04:50 _usr_bin_gnome-keyring-daemon.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   681075 Jul 17 04:50 _usr_bin_gnome-keyring-daemon.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 sumner   whoopsie  1935512 Jul 17 04:49 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     whoopsie        0 Jul 17 04:49 .lock
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 13 07:53 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-4.0_WebKitWebProcess.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r--  1 sumner   whoopsie        0 Jul 13 07:53 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-4.0_WebKitWebProcess.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 sumner   whoopsie  3481818 Jul 13 07:53 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-4.0_WebKitWebProcess.1000.crash
```

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            30G        1.2G         28G        670M        1.4G         28G
Swap:           31G          0B         31G
```

swapon -s:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   32964604    0   -1
```

Extensions:

```
Installed Extensions
Add Username to Top Panel  by brendaw ONOFF

AlternateTab  by fmuellner ONOFF

Applications Menu  by fmuellner ONOFF

Auto Move Windows  by fmuellner ONOFF

Dash to Dock  by michele_g ONOFF

Extensions  by petres ONOFF

Files Menu  by bertoldia ONOFF

Force Quit  by megh ONOFF

Launch new instance  by fmuellner ONOFF

Native Window Placement  by fmuellner ONOFF

Nvidia GPU Temperature Indicator  by baco ONOFF


Public IP Address  by growing ONOFF

Removable Drive Menu  by fmuellner ONOFF

Screenshot Window Sizer  by fmuellner ONOFF

Switcher  by dlandau ONOFF


User Themes  by fmuellner ONOFF

Window List  by fmuellner ONOFF

windowNavigator  by fmuellner ONOFF

Workspace Indicator  by fmuellner ONOFF
```

Some other things:

```
nvidia-prime
libinput-gestures (known to be unstable)
tlp
```

Comment: Is GNOME Shell crashing? In `terminal` do `ls -alt /var/crash` and see what's at the top of the list, as that's the most recent crash. What are the others? If GNOME Shell is crashing you've probably got a bad GNOME extension.

Comment: @heynnema I added the crash log

Comment: My my. You've got a very unstable system. Probably due to "lots of drivers and customization to hunt down / tweak to get acceptable performance". Tell me what GNOME extensions you have installed and enabled, and what drivers. How much RAM and swap? Use `free -h` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: ps: and what Startup Applications?

Comment: @heynnema added some more info. None that I know of.

Comment: Open `Startup Applications` app and check there.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

re: *"My my. You've got a very unstable system. Probably due to "lots of drivers and customization to hunt down / tweak to get acceptable performance".*

Please temporarily disable **ALL** GNOME extensions that are **NOT** by author `fmuellner`. `Dash to Dock` is OK, you can leave that one enabled. Run your system and see if it runs more stable. Keep in mind that you may have more than one actual problem causing your crashes.

Monitor `/var/crash` with `ls -alt /var/crash`, looking for crashes, even ones that you may not be aware of.

Once you've established a baseline that your system runs without problems, we can start enabling GNOME extensions ONE AT A TIME, until instability reoccurs again.

**Update #1:**

- we've disabled all GNOME extensions not by author `fmuellner` (Dash to Dock is OK)
- we've disabled `Caribou`, `libinput-gestures`, and `Welcome`, in `Startup Applications`

**Update #2:**

Update your question to include the latest `ls -alt /var/crash` so I can see what's changed.

To review `syslog`, in `terminal` type `more /var/log/syslog`. This will show you the current syslog (there's more than one) on your screen. Page through it, looking for some error that repeats itself a lot, or some lines that start with ERROR, WARNING, or FATAL. Pay close attention to the time on each line, and as you approach the time of the last freeze/crash/logout incident, pay closer attention to each line, looking for an event that occurred just before the freeze/crash/logout incident, or just before a reboot. That would be most important. Copy/paste any lines that you think are important for me to see.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62425/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-gnome-3-16-04-lts-front-end-crash-during-logout).